# How Can I Change Global CSS

Tags: css, global, slick.js

My website has a Slick-Slider which is not full screen at this moment. I want to do it full screen. So when I inspect the website I can see this code;

```
@media (min-width: 768px) .col-md-9 {flex: 0 0 75%;max-width: 75%;}
```

This code comes from Global.css which I dont have it in my theme folders.
When I change max-width to 100% on inspect slider becomes full screen when I paste this code to my css file nothing happens. How can I mport this code to my CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just include it normally in your CSS. Local CSS takes precedence over global CSS settings. IF you are able to, make sure that your CSS document is included after the global one.

Comment: Thank you I removed @media section and it worked thanks alot!